# Not able to pair Raspberry Pi 3 and iBeacon using Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, ibeacon, raspberry-pi3

In my current project, I am working with iBeacon in the area of IoT. Basically iBeacon works on Bluetooth wireless technology. I am using Raspberry Pi 3 (which is available with in-built wifi and bluetooth). Pi 3 Bluetooth display and detect the iBeacon but not able to do pairing with it and display the following error:

```
GDBus.Error:org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationFailed
```

I also tried with bluetoothctl command also but again display the  `Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationFailed`
error.

Am I missing something? I am able to pair iBeacon with my mobile and windows based lapotop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understand that iBeacon is a transmit only Bluetooth LE device.  It is Bluetooth LE manufacturer advertisements to send a unique identifier, something you have seen if you have detected it with the Raspberry Pi 3.

But a basic iBeacon device is not designed to be connectable over Bluetooth LE.  Some beacon manufacturers may expose a secondary configuration service that is connectable, but this is not universal and if it exists it is entirely outside the beacon spec.

Bottom line: you are not supposed to be able to connect.

If you have a specific model of beacon that does have a config interface, and you want to connect to that, you may want to put that in your question.